# Early 80s YA Science Fiction Anthology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult

I'm seeking the identification of a science fiction short story collection I saw in a Maine public library in the early 80s.

I most strongly remember the ending of one story where a group of astronauts were walking and a robot that was with them told them to stop because there was danger up ahead. They laughed, told the robot there was nothing ahead, and kept walking and then ended up stepping into quicksand. They begged the robot for help, but it told them it wasn't allowed to put itself into danger and all the astronauts ended up drowning.

The anthology was illustrated, I recall two, one for this story with the astronauts disappearing into the quicksand, and for a different story that was a picture of a dinosaur being scooped up by a payloader.

Every now and then I spend a great amount of time putting in different Google searches with no luck (that's how I came across this site) and if somebody could solve the mystery I would be ecstatic.

Comment: Was this a young adult anthology?

Comment: Yes it was, I remember looking at it in the children's section of the library.